# how to get uploaded file full path in javascript. Always it returns c:\fakepath. I want full path for my servlet

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

How can I  get the full path of an  uploaded file in [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)? It always returns `c:\fakepath`. This file path is sent directly to the controller using jquery. So, I want the full path for my servlet. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is blocked for security reasons.

Browsers hide the full path because it's a breach in security if the website could see the full path to a file you've selected.

Comment: ok. how can i get it from background process?